# Openbr-1.1.0 example script files

Tags: c++, face-recognition, openbr

- I am working on face recognition project.For that i am using **Openbr-v1.1.0** library.
- I want test it by executable files given in **openbr-1.1/app/examples/**.But exactly don't know how to test them.i am getting SDK path error.
- Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the error / code etc?